# uwp c#, is it possible to refer single variable for different types of control?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
var _textbox;
if (datatype == "STRING") {
  _textbox = new TextBox();
  _textbox.Text = "text";
}
else if (dataype == "ACTOR") {
  _textbox = new AutoSuggestBox();
}

_textbox.Tag = "custom tag name";
grid.Children.Add(_textbox);
Grid.SetRow(_textbox, row);
```

I don't want to repeat same code for all control types (setting tag and appending child to grid).
Is there a way for that?

Comment: What's `AutoSuggestionBox` class?

Comment: It would be great if you used real code. There's no `.text` property, for example.

Comment: Sorry, updated the code

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARS Ok I wrote an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the extract method to avoid duplicate code.

If you use `children` it might be [UIElementCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) which `add` method need to pass `System.Windows.UIElement` class.

```
Control _textbox = GetTextBox();
_textbox.Tag = "custom tag name";

grid.Children.Add(_textbox);
Grid.SetRow(_textbox, row);


public Control GetControl(){
    Control _textbox;
    if (condition1) {
      _textbox = GetTextBox();
    }
    else if (condition2) {
      _textbox = new AutoSuggestBox();
    }
    return _textbox;
}

public TextBox GetTextBox(){
    TextBox _textbox = new TextBox();
    _textbox.Text = "text";
    return _textbox;
}
```

Or you can try to use I saw you edit your question, you can try to use `Dictionary` be a mapper table then use `TryGetValue` to make it.

```
Dictionary<string, Control> dict = new Dictionary<string, Control>();
dict.Add("STRING", new TextBox() { Text = "text" });
dict.Add("ACTOR", new AutoSuggestBox());

Control _textbox;
if (dict.TryGetValue(datatype, out _textbox))
{
    _textbox.Tag = "custom tag name";
    grid.Children.Add(_textbox);
    Grid.SetRow(_textbox, row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do this:

```
Control _textbox = null;
if (datatype == "STRING")
{
    _textbox = new TextBox();
    _textbox.Text = "text";
}
else if (dataype == "ACTOR")
{
    _textbox = new AutoSuggestBox();
}

if (_textbox != null)
{
    _textbox.Tag = "custom tag name";
    grid.Children.Add(_textbox);
    Grid.SetRow(_textbox, row);
}
```